# mithril rendering "background-image url"

Tags: background-image, mithril.js

I have the following issue with mithril

Image is display properly when it is a proper img tag

```
`<img src="images/erp/C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CMYTEST%5Cbitmaps%5C10001.jpg"  class="scale">`
```

But same image not rendered at all when it is set as  background-image url

```
`background-image: url("images/erp/C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CMYTEST%5Cbitmaps%5C10001.jpg");`
```

Comment: It looks like you're using a template literal to define a string representing a CSS property value map. How are you applying this in your Mithril code?

Comment: It look strange to have a "C:/Program Files" path in your image source path. Are you sure of your path? You should copy the image in a simpler path in the image/erp folder for example and try again to see if your css property is correctly interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/issues/996/) the cause is a bug in [mithril.sj](/questions/tagged/mithril.sj) the string `C:\Tmp\a\field.png` is converted into `"C:Tmpa\f ield.png"`

This javascript:

```
view: function (ctrl) {
 return [m("button", [m("img[src='C:\\Tmp\\a\\field.png\']"),"btn img"]),
  m("div", {'style': { 'background-image' : 'url(\"field.png\")'}},"div a"),
  m("div", {'style': { 'background-image' : 'url(\"C:\\Tmp\\a\\field.png\")'}},"div b")];
}
```

is rendered to this html

```
<button><img src="C:\Temp\mith\field.png">img inside a btn</button>
<div style="background-image: url("field.png");">no path</div>
<div style="background-image: url("C:Tmp\a\f ield.png");">with path</div>
```

Comment: Yea actully I raised this issue with Mithril